# Pasar dos variables a un metodo en laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, método

Ayuda estoy estancado en una parte de mi proyecto, estoy realizando una intranet para un Liceo. EL tema es que quiero colocar una "Observacion" a un Alumno, para esto necesito el "id" del Alumno, el "id" de la Asignatura, y el "id" del Profesor que esta Autentificado. En una vista tengo todos los alumnos de una asignatura.

[image: Vista alumnos por asignatura]

Al seleccionar añadir conducta (el icono rojo de la derecha) recibo la "id" del alumno y de la asignatura en este controlador

```
public function agregarAnotacion($id, $id)
{   
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);

    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($id);

    return view('agregaranotacion')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('asignatura',$asignatura);
}
```

La "id" del profesor la obtendre con el Auth. Pero nose como puedo almacenar esto en mi base de datos ya que el metodo create() y store() de laravel viene sin variables. Tengo que crear otro metodo para almacenarlas? o puedo usar el mismo create(), store()? y si es asi como quedaria?. gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando das clic en anadir conducta, podrias tener un form en donde este como campos ocultos el:

- id del alumno

- id de asignatura

- id del maestro.

- observacion

Esto lo mandas en el formulario

```
 Lo recibis de la siguiente manera.

public function store(Request $request){
 // obtenes los datos enviados
 $idAlumno = $request->id_alumno;
 $idAsignatura = $request->id_asignatura;
 $idProfesor = $request->id_profesor;
 $Obseervacion = $request->observacion;

creas un array con los valores obtenidos, la columna de la izquierda son los
nombre de tus campos de la base de datos y la derecha los valores obtenidos

 $dataSaveObservacion = array(
   'id_alumno' => $idAlumno,
   'id_asignatura' => $idAsignatura,
   'id_profesor' => $idProfesor,
   'observacion' => $Obseervacion ,
  );

 llamas tu tabla
$AddObservacion = new Observaciones($dataSaveObservacion );  

Guardas
  $AddObservacion->save();


}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta ahora tengo otra dduda